# Efficient least-significant digit (LSD) radix sort for int and long keys in Java - iteration II

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, radix-sort

This post elaborates on [Efficient least-significant digit (LSD) radix sort for int keys in Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/290982/efficient-least-significant-digit-lsd-radix-sort-for-int-keys-in-java). This time, I made mild corrections to my code and provided the radix sort for `long` keys too.

### Code

**`com.github.coderodde.util.LsdRadixsort.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * This class provides the method for sorting {@code int} arrays using 
 * least-significant digit (LSD) radix sort.
 */
public final class LsdRadixsort {
    
    /**
     * The number of counters in the counter array.
     */
    private static final int RADIX = 256;
    
    private LsdRadixsort() {
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Sorts the entire {@code int} array into ascending order.
     * 
     * @param array the array to sort. 
     */
    public static void sort(int[] array) {
        sort(array, 0, array.length);
    }
    
    /**
     * Sorts the entire {@code long} array into ascending order.
     * 
     * @param array the array to sort. 
     */
    public static void sort(long[] array) {
        sort(array, 0, array.length);
    }
    
    /**
     * Sorts the range {@code array[fromIndex ... toIndex - 1]} into ascending
     * order.
     * 
     * @param array     the array holding the range.
     * @param fromIndex the starting, inclusive index of the sorting range.
     * @param toIndex   the ending, exclusive index of the sorting range. 
     */
    public static void sort(int[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        checkRangeIndices(array.length,
                          fromIndex,
                          toIndex);
        
        int rangeLength = toIndex - fromIndex;
        
        if (rangeLength < 2) {
            // Trivially sorted:
            return;
        }
        
        // buffer and counterMap are allocated only once for the sake of 
        // performance:
        int[] buffer = new int[rangeLength];
        int[] counterMap = new int[RADIX];
        
        sortImpl(array,
                 buffer, 
                 counterMap,
                 fromIndex,
                 toIndex);
    }
    
    /**
     * Sorts the range {@code array[fromIndex ... toIndex - 1]} into ascending
     * order.
     * 
     * @param array     the array holding the range.
     * @param fromIndex the starting, inclusive index of the sorting range.
     * @param toIndex   the ending, exclusive index of the sorting range. 
     */
    public static void sort(long[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        checkRangeIndices(array.length,
                          fromIndex,
                          toIndex);
        
        int rangeLength = toIndex - fromIndex;
        
        if (rangeLength < 2) {
            // Trivially sorted:
            return;
        }
        
        // buffer and counterMap are allocated only once for the sake of 
        // performance:
        long[] buffer = new long[rangeLength];
        int[] counterMap = new int[RADIX];
        
        sortImpl(array,
                 buffer, 
                 counterMap,
                 fromIndex,
                 toIndex);
    }
    
    /**
     * Implements the actual sorting.
     * 
     * @param array      the array to sort.
     * @param buffer     the sorting buffer array.
     * @param counterMap the bucket counter array.
     * @param fromIndex  the starting, inclusive index of the sorting range.
     * @param toIndex    the ending, exclsuive index of the sorting range.
     */
    private static void sortImpl(int[] array,
                                 int[] buffer, 
                                 int[] counterMap,
                                 int fromIndex,
                                 int toIndex) {
        // Sort first by least-significant bytes, then by second 
        // least-significant, and finally by third least-signficant byte:
        for (int byteIndex = 0; byteIndex < 3; byteIndex++) {
            countingSortImpl(array, 
                             buffer, 
                             counterMap, 
                             byteIndex,
                             fromIndex,
                             toIndex);
        }
        
        // Deal with the signed data:
        countingSortImplSigned(array, 
                               buffer, 
                               counterMap,
                               fromIndex,
                               toIndex);
    }
    
    /**
     * Implements the actual sorting.
     * 
     * @param array      the array to sort.
     * @param buffer     the sorting buffer array.
     * @param counterMap the bucket counter array.
     * @param fromIndex  the starting, inclusive index of the sorting range.
     * @param toIndex    the ending, exclsuive index of the sorting range.
     */
    private static void sortImpl(long[] array,
                                 long[] buffer, 
                                 int[] counterMap,
                                 int fromIndex,
                                 int toIndex) {
        // Sort first by least-significant bytes, then by second 
        // least-significant, and finally by third least-signficant byte:
        for (int byteIndex = 0; byteIndex < 7; byteIndex++) {
            countingSortImpl(array, 
                             buffer, 
                             counterMap, 
                             byteIndex,
                             fromIndex,
                             toIndex);
        }
        
        // Deal with the signed data:
        countingSortImplSigned(array, 
                               buffer, 
                               counterMap,
                               fromIndex,
                               toIndex);
    }
    
    /**
     * Performs the counting sort on {@code array[fromIndex ... toIndex - 1]}.
     * 
     * @param array      the array to sort.
     * @param buffer     the buffer array.
     * @param counterMap the counter array. We reuse this in order not to
     *                   allocate it everytime we call this method.
     * @param byteIndex  the index of the byte that serves as the sorting key.
     * @param fromIndex  the starting, inclusive index of the sorting range.
     * @param toIndex    the ending, exclusive index of the sorting range.
     */
    private static void countingSortImpl(int[] array,
                                         int[] buffer,
                                         int[] counterMap,
                                         int byteIndex,
                                         int fromIndex,
                                         int toIndex) {
        Arrays.fill(counterMap, 0);
        
        // Count the elements:
        for (int i = fromIndex; i != toIndex; i++) {
            counterMap[extractCounterIndex(array[i], byteIndex)]++;
        }

        // Make the counter map accummulative:
        for (int i = 1; i != RADIX; i++) {
            counterMap[i] += counterMap[i - 1];
        }
        
        // Build the buffer array (which will end up sorted):
        for (int i = toIndex - 1; i >= fromIndex; i--) {
            int index = extractCounterIndex(array[i], byteIndex);
            buffer[--counterMap[index]] = array[i];
        }
        
        // Just copy the buffer to the array:
        System.arraycopy(buffer, 
                         0, 
                         array,
                         fromIndex, 
                         buffer.length);
    }
    
    /**
     * Performs the counting sort on {@code array[fromIndex ... toIndex - 1]}.
     * 
     * @param array      the array to sort.
     * @param buffer     the buffer array.
     * @param counterMap the counter array. We reuse this in order not to
     *                   allocate it everytime we call this method.
     * @param byteIndex  the index of the byte that serves as the sorting key.
     * @param fromIndex  the starting, inclusive index of the sorting range.
     * @param toIndex    the ending, exclusive index of the sorting range.
     */
    private static void countingSortImpl(long[] array,
                                         long[] buffer,
                                         int[] counterMap,
                                         int byteIndex,
                                         int fromIndex,
                                         int toIndex) {
        Arrays.fill(counterMap, 0);
        
        // Count the elements:
        for (int i = fromIndex; i != toIndex; i++) {
            counterMap[extractCounterIndex(array[i], byteIndex)]++;
        }

        // Make the counter map accummulative:
        for (int i = 1; i != RADIX; i++) {
            counterMap[i] += counterMap[i - 1];
        }
        
        // Build the buffer array (which will end up sorted):
        for (int i = toIndex - 1; i >= fromIndex; i--) {
            int index = extractCounterIndex(array[i], byteIndex);
            buffer[--counterMap[index]] = array[i];
        }
        
        // Just copy the buffer to the array:
        System.arraycopy(buffer, 
                         0, 
                         array,
                         fromIndex, 
                         buffer.length);
    }
    
    /**
     * Sorts the {@code array[fromIndex ... toIndex - 1]} by most significant 
     * bytes that contain the sign bits.
     * 
     * @param array      the array to sort.
     * @param buffer     the buffer array.
     * @param counterMap the counter map. We pass this array in order not to 
     *                   create it in this method.
     * @param fromIndex  the starting, inclusive index of the sorting range.
     * @param toIndex    the ending, exclusive index of the sorting range.
     */
    private static void countingSortImplSigned(int[] array,
                                               int[] buffer,
                                               int[] counterMap,
                                               int fromIndex,
                                               int toIndex) {
        Arrays.fill(counterMap, 0);
        
        // Count the elements:
        for (int i = fromIndex; i != toIndex; i++) {
            counterMap[extractCounterIndexSigned(array[i])]++;
        }

        // Make the counter map accummulative:
        for (int i = 1; i != RADIX; i++) {
            counterMap[i] += counterMap[i - 1];
        }
        
        // Build the output array:
        for (int i = toIndex - 1; i >= fromIndex; i--) {
            int index = extractCounterIndexSigned(array[i]);
            buffer[--counterMap[index]] = array[i];
        }
        
        // Just copy the buffer to the array:
        System.arraycopy(buffer, 
                         0, 
                         array,
                         fromIndex, 
                         buffer.length);
    }
    
    /**
     * Sorts the {@code array[fromIndex ... toIndex - 1]} by most significant 
     * bytes that contain the sign bits.
     * 
     * @param array      the array to sort.
     * @param buffer     the buffer array.
     * @param counterMap the counter map. We pass this array in order not to 
     *                   create it in this method.
     * @param fromIndex  the starting, inclusive index of the sorting range.
     * @param toIndex    the ending, exclusive index of the sorting range.
     */
    private static void countingSortImplSigned(long[] array,
                                               long[] buffer,
                                               int[] counterMap,
                                               int fromIndex,
                                               int toIndex) {
        Arrays.fill(counterMap, 0);
        
        // Count the elements:
        for (int i = fromIndex; i != toIndex; i++) {
            counterMap[extractCounterIndexSigned(array[i])]++;
        }

        // Make the counter map accummulative:
        for (int i = 1; i != RADIX; i++) {
            counterMap[i] += counterMap[i - 1];
        }
        
        // Build the output array:
        for (int i = toIndex - 1; i >= fromIndex; i--) {
            int index = extractCounterIndexSigned(array[i]);
            buffer[--counterMap[index]] = array[i];
        }
        
        // Just copy the buffer to the array:
        System.arraycopy(buffer, 
                         0, 
                         array,
                         fromIndex, 
                         buffer.length);
    }
    
    /**
     * Extracts the counter array index from the integer datum.
     * 
     * @param datum     the integer key.
     * @param byteIndex the index of the byte of the key to consider.
     * @return          the index into counter array.
     */
    private static int extractCounterIndex(int datum, int byteIndex) {
        // Shift so that the target byte is the leftmost byte and set to zero
        // all the remaining bits:
        return (datum >>> (byteIndex * 8)) & 0xff;
    }
    
    /**
     * Extracts the counter array index from the integer datum. Considers only
     * the most significant byte that contains the sign bit. The sign bit is 
     * flipped in order to put the datum in correct location in the counter 
     * array.
     * 
     * @param datum the integer key.
     * @return      the index into counter array. 
     */
    private static int extractCounterIndexSigned(int datum) {
        // We use xor ^ operator in order to flip the bit index 7 (8th bit from
        // the least significant end):
        return (datum >>> 24) ^ 0b1000_0000;
    }
    
    /**
     * Extracts the counter array index from the {@code long} integer datum.
     * 
     * @param datum     the {@code long} integer key.
     * @param byteIndex the index of the byte of the key to consider.
     * @return          the index into counter array.
     */
    private static int extractCounterIndex(long datum, int byteIndex) {
        return (int)((datum >>> (byteIndex * 8)) & 0xffL);
    }
    
    /**
     * Extracts the counter array index from the {@code long} integer datum. 
     * Considers only the most significant byte that contains the sign bit. The 
     * sign bit is flipped in order to put the datum in correct location in the 
     * counter array.
     * 
     * @param datum the {@code long} integer key.
     * @return      the index into counter array. 
     */
    private static int extractCounterIndexSigned(long datum) {
        return (int)((datum >>> 56) ^ 0b1000_0000);
    }
    
    /**
     * Checks that the specified sorting range is reasonable.
     * 
     * @param arrayLength the total length of the target array.
     * @param fromIndex   the starting, inclusive index of the sorting range.
     * @param toIndex     the ending, exclusive index of the sorting range.
     */
    private static void checkRangeIndices(int arrayLength, 
                                          int fromIndex,
                                          int toIndex) {
        if (fromIndex < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    String.format(
                            "fromIndex(%d) is negative. Must be at least 0.", 
                            fromIndex));
        }
        
        if (toIndex > arrayLength) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    String.format(
                            "toIndex(%d) is too large. Must be at most %d.",
                            toIndex, 
                            arrayLength));
        }
        
        if (fromIndex > toIndex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    String.format(
                            "toIndex(%d) > fromIndex(%d).", 
                            toIndex,
                            fromIndex));
        }
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.util.demo.LsdRadixsortDemo.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util.demo;

import com.github.coderodde.util.LsdRadixsort;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class LsdRadixsortDemo {
    
    private static final int LENGTH = 100_000_000;
    private static final int PREFIX_SUFFIX_EXCLUSION_RANGE_LENGTH = 50;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Random random = new Random(seed);
        
        int fromIndex = 
                random.nextInt(PREFIX_SUFFIX_EXCLUSION_RANGE_LENGTH + 1);
        
        int toIndex = LENGTH - random.nextInt(
                        PREFIX_SUFFIX_EXCLUSION_RANGE_LENGTH + 1);
        
        System.out.printf("Seed = %d.\n", seed);
        
        ////// int array:
        
        System.out.println("--- int arrays ---");
        
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int[] intArray1 = createRandomIntegerArray(LENGTH, random);
        int[] intArray2 = intArray1.clone();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        System.out.printf("Built demo int arrays in %d milliseconds.\n", 
                          endTime - startTime);
        
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LsdRadixsort.sort(intArray1, fromIndex, toIndex);
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long durationRadixsort = endTime - startTime;
        
        System.out.printf("LSDRadixsort took %d milliseconds.\n", 
                          durationRadixsort);
        
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Arrays.sort(intArray2, fromIndex, toIndex);
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long durationArraysSort = endTime - startTime;
        
        System.out.printf("Arrays.sort took %d milliseconds.\n", 
                          durationArraysSort);
        
        System.out.printf("Arrays agree: %b.\n",
                          Arrays.equals(intArray1,
                                        intArray2));
        
        float ratio = (float) durationRadixsort / (float) durationArraysSort;
        
        System.out.println(
                String.format(
                        "Time ratio: %.3f.\n", ratio)
                        .replace(',', '.'));
        
        intArray1 = null;
        intArray2 = null;
        System.gc();
        
        ////// long array:
        
        System.out.println("--- long arrays ---");
        
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long[] longArray1 = createRandomLongIntegerArray(LENGTH, random);
        long[] longArray2 = longArray1.clone();
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        System.out.printf("Built demo long arrays in %d milliseconds.\n",
                          endTime - startTime);
        
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LsdRadixsort.sort(longArray1, fromIndex, toIndex);
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        durationRadixsort = endTime - startTime;
        
        System.out.printf("LSDRadixsort took %d milliseconds.\n", 
                          durationRadixsort);
        
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Arrays.sort(longArray2, fromIndex, toIndex);
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        durationArraysSort = endTime - startTime;
        
        System.out.printf("Arrays.sort took %d milliseconds.\n", 
                          durationArraysSort);
        
        System.out.printf("Arrays agree: %b.\n",
                          Arrays.equals(longArray1,
                                        longArray2));
        
        ratio = (float) durationRadixsort / (float) durationArraysSort;
        
        System.out.println(
                String.format(
                        "Time ratio: %.3f.\n", ratio)
                        .replace(',', '.'));
        
        longArray1 = null;
        longArray2 = null;
        System.gc();
    }
    
    private static short[] createRandomShortArray(int length, Random random) {
        short[] array = new short[length];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            array[i] = (short) random.nextInt();
        }
        
        return array;
    }
    
    private static int[] createRandomIntegerArray(int length, Random random) {
        int[] array = new int[length];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            array[i] = random.nextInt();
        }
        
        return array;
    }
    
    private static long[] createRandomLongIntegerArray(int length, 
                                                       Random random) {
        long[] array = new long[length];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            array[i] = random.nextInt();
        }
        
        return array;
    }
}
```

### Typical output

```
Seed = 1710512066995.
--- int arrays ---
Built demo int arrays in 2916 milliseconds.
LSDRadixsort took 3074 milliseconds.
Arrays.sort took 16393 milliseconds.
Arrays agree: true.
Time ratio: 0.188.

--- long arrays ---
Built demo long arrays in 1874 milliseconds.
LSDRadixsort took 5880 milliseconds.
Arrays.sort took 16493 milliseconds.
Arrays agree: true.
Time ratio: 0.357.
```

### Critique request

As always, I am eager to receive any commentary of my work.

Comment: I think using `random.nextInt()` in `createRandomLongIntegerArray()` creates an unexpected distribution.

Comment: @greybeard True, but even with `random.nextInt(1000)`, the LSD radix sort for `int`s is 42% faster than `Arrays.sort`.